# How to import StructuredArgument for structured logging in scala using slf4j and logback

Tags: scala, logstash, logback, slf4j, structured-logging

This is probably a stupid question, but my scala knowledge is a bit lacking.  I'm trying to implement structured logging in scala, and we're using slf4j/logback/logstash.  I came across the following post: [How does SLF4J support structured logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430644/how-does-slf4j-support-structured-logging) Which describes how to do it:

```
import static net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.*;

/*
 * Add "name":"value" ONLY to the JSON output.
 *
 * Since there is no parameter for the argument,
 * the formatted message will NOT contain the key/value.
 *
 * If this looks funny to you or to static analyzers,
 * consider using Markers instead.
 */
logger.info("log message", keyValue("name", "value"));
```

Obviously this is java code, not scala.  I've converted it over, but I can't get it to find net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.KeyValue.  I'm guessing this is because it's not being included in the build, but this is where I'm tripping up.

I'm using sbt, and I'm including what I expect the package to be:

```
"net.logstash.logback" %% "logstash-logback-encoder" % VersionOf.`logstash`
```

However sbt cannot find that package (version is 1.2.1).  What's also confusing me is that our other dependencies for logback are pulled from the group id: ch.qos.logback.  I don't really understand what ch.qos.logback is and why it's different from net.logstash.logback.

Long story short, what package do I need to import with sbt so that I can use StructuredArguments/KeyValues for my logging?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?